How to access the app battery optimization settings on Android 12 and above?
The menu appears to have been hidden on the more recent Android releases — currently on  Android 14 the only per-app toggle the users are given is 'allow background usage' (app info → app battery usage). On my Oneplus 8T device the OS is actively stopping some apps designed to be running on the background at all times, such as Shizuku.
On AOSP-based ROMs three settings used to be available for each app, the most permissive being 'unrestricted'. SystemUI Tuner didn't expose the menu.


Using ADB is an acceptable answer as well.

What is your phone's model? When you open Settings and search 'optimization', does it show/list Battery optimization or not?

@ReddyLutonadio Oneplus 8T with LineageOS 21 (Android 14). No, after typing optim, the settings' search no longer displays any results.

What happens if you follow the following steps: Settings → Apps → App battery usage → YourApp → Allow background usage (tap the text, not the toggle)

FWIW, since the question mentions Android 12, Pixel 3a on stock Android 12L and Galaxy M12 on stock Android 13 still have the Battery menu on per-app settings with 3 options shown on the screenshot. Perhaps some info from Don't kill my app! might help?

SetEdit is always an option, though you may need to grant additional permissions via ADB first.

@ReddyLutonadio By "tapping the text" next to the toggle I was able to access the familiar 'unrestricted' and 'optimised' values (screenshot)! Please post an answer.

Based on this answer from Reddit, the following steps allow to view the battery optimisation settings for individual apps:

Settings → Apps → App battery usage → [$APP] → Allow background usage (tap the text, not the toggle)

[$APP] being the app you want to verify the battery optimisation's setting.
